# Is it safe for me to root my s7 sm-g930f model phone

Tags: rooting, root-access, 7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy-s7

I would like to know if it is worth me rooting my galaxy s7 sm g930f phone and if there are any problems after its done.   thank you

Comment: this website has extensive answers regarding the risks and benefits of rooting.

Answer (score 0):

Define "*safe*" and "*worth*".

It *will* void your warranty, and you will risk bricking, blocking or otherwise ruining your phone, so it is anything but safe.

It will also open the possibility of custom ROMs, modding, debloating, theming, hacking, backing up, extended updates support for recent versions of Android beyond what the manufacturer provides.

All this at the expense of stability, bugs and probably worse battery life, and likely also a bunch of proprietary features like better camera and custom device features.

Point is this is really a matter of personal opinion. Are those downsides really worth it for you?

I am a strong proponent of rooting and custom ROMs especially to get rid of all the bloat and benefit from extra features, but it is admittedly a risk and requires knowhow and dedication.

Comment: In short: That depends on your own need